# A simple OOP understanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oop

I have a class:

```
public class TaskDiplayModel
{
    public int taskId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Task Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Priority")]
    public string priority { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("State")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Due By")]
    public DateTime deadline { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public PersonObject created_by { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Assigned To")]
    public PersonObject assigned_to { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public string category { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Sub Category")]
    public string subCategory { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Created")]
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Updated")]
    public DateTime lastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Updated By")]
    public PersonObject lastUpdatedBy { get; set; }    
}
```

I then have another class which inherits from this class:

```
public class TaskModifyModel : TaskDiplayModel
{
    public int priorityId { get; set; }
    public int stateId { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public int subCategoryId { get; set; }

    public SelectList states { get; private set; }
    public SelectList priorities { get; private set; }
    public SelectList categories { get; private set; }
    public SelectList subCategories { get; private set; }

    public TaskModifyModel()
    {
        SetupReferenceData(0);
    }

    public TaskModifyModel(int taskId)
    {

        var taskService = new TaskService();
        var task = taskService.GetTask(taskId);
    }
}
```

In my application, I create a `TaskModifyModel` object. However, string fields from the base class are `null`. I'd expect them to have been created and be `String.Empty`. But I get exception when I try to access them. Am I missing something?

These are MVC3 Models, by the way.... And code from the classes have been omitted as I think it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: BTW, normal .NET conventions has capitals for the first letter of property and method names. There's no rule that you have to do that, but matching conventions used by the framework itself is always a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in .NET, the default value for a string is `null`, not `String.Empty`, so unless you specifically set the values of the properties to `String.Empty`, they will remain `null`.

Assuming you want your string properties to default to an empty string instead of null, you would normally do this either by setting them in the constructor:

```
public void TaskDiplayModel()
{
    description = String.Empty;
    priority = String.Empty;
    state = String.Empty;
}
```

Or by using a field-backed property instead of an auto property, and setting the backing field:

```
private string _description = String.Empty;

[DisplayName("Task Description")]
public string description
{
    get { return _description; }
    set { _description = value; }
}
```

Personally I usually use the first option, doing it in the constructor, because it is less to code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to rally25rs' excellent answer (+1 from me anyway), given the following abridged version:

```
public class TaskDiplayModel
{
    private string _priority = string.Empty;
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Priority
    {
       get { return _priority; }
       set { _priority = value; }
    }
    public TaskDisplayMode()
    {
      Description = string.Empty;
    }
}
public class TaskModifyModel : TaskDisplayMode
{
  public int PriorityId { get; set; }
  public TaskModifyModel()
    :base()
  {
    PriorityId = 3;
  }
}
```

Then the order upon construction of `TaskModifyModel` is as follows:

1. Set `_priority` to `string.Empty`, `TaskId` to `0`, `PriorityId` to `0`, and `Description` to `null` (if no value is stated, everything gets set to `null` if a reference, `0` if a number, and structs get set to having their fields full of `0` and `null`).
2. If the constructor body of `TaskDiplayModel` is executed, setting `Description` to `string.Empty`.
3. The constructor body of `TaskModifyModel` is executed, setting `PriorityId` to `3`.

And so on if the nested inheritance is more complicated. As a rule, you can expect some of this to be optimised, so don't worry about whether it would be faster or slower to take a different approach as to how you set a value - it won't, except in debug runs. It does though explain the rule of avoiding calling virtual methods within constructors - most of the time we don't need to care about the ordering above and just treat the constructor as a single unit after which we have a fully constructed object, but if you start playing with virtual calls then the above ordering becomes very important because at one point `PriorityId` is `0`, and at another its `3`.